# Placing an image in ListBoxItem in XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I wonder if is possible to add an image to a ListBoxItem in xaml.
I try it this way:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
             <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}"></Image>
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

and it worked but I would like to see if there is another way without using template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't think of a better way to do this. Why do you not wish to use the template?

Comment: The list is used to display options and is fixed, so I want to see alternatives to not have to do it behind the code

Comment: You can always hard code items in your list box: `<ListBox Width="150" Margin="0,5,0,10">
    <Image Source="myPicture.png" />
    <TextBox Text="TextBox" />
    <Button Content="Button"  />
    <Rectangle Fill="LightBlue" Height="20" Width="100"  Margin="2,2,2,2"/>
    <Ellipse Fill="Coral" Height="20" Width="150"  Margin="2,2,2,2"/>
</ListBox>`

Comment: Thanks that gave me an idea something like this was what I wanted:
`<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="settings.png" Width="16" Height="16" />
           <ListBoxItem Content="Settings" Tag="SETTINGS" Width="130"></ListBoxItem>
       </StackPanel>`